# Multiple audio buttons: change class of previously playing button when a new one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have multiple `.player-button` elements, each with its own audio.

The clicked element plays the audio, pauses the previously playing element and changes class to `.playing`.

The problem is that I need to click again on the `.playing` element to change it's class to `.paused`. That means that when I click another `.player-button` the paused one does not change its class to `.paused` as long as I don't click on it. That means if the user just clicks on the various elements, he will be seeing a whole bunch of nice pause icons!

Here is the FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/VitoLattarulo/mdcan81n/14/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".player-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var song = $(this).prev('audio').get(0);

    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      $(this).addClass("playing");
      $(this).removeClass("paused");
    } else {
      song.pause();
      $(this).addClass("paused");
      $(this).removeClass("playing");
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for (var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (audios[i] != e.target) {
        audios[i].pause();
      }
    }
  }, true);
});
```

I evidently need a way to merge the two functions together but I am still a newbie and cannot figure out how to do it.

I would really appreciate a lot any help! It's the last issue to solve before I can publish my first website ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using the classes to determine the button state and only using them for styling, I would just remove all `paused` and `playing` classes when any button is clicked then reset the classes as needed like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".player-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this=$(this); // cache this
    var song = $this.prev('audio').get(0);
    $(".player-button").removeClass("paused playing");
    if (song.paused) {
      song.play();
      $this.addClass("playing");
    } else {
      song.pause();
      $this.addClass("paused");
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for (var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (audios[i] != e.target) {
        audios[i].pause();
      }
    }
  }, true);
  document.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    $(".player-button").removeClass("paused playing");
  }, true);

});
```

#### [Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdcan81n/18/)

Comment: I just noticed that at the end of the track the icon remaines paused. Is there a way to give it the finishing touch and change the class back to `paused` after the track has ended? Here I really have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Vito do you mean *"at the end of the track the icon remains playing"*? For that youll need to use `addEventListener('ended'`, see my update above :)

Comment: You are right, that's exactly what I meant. It works perfectly and you are a master! I am learning so much here! Thank you :)